# Div not filling out even at min-height:100%;

Tags: html, css, angular

So I'm currently still new to angular as a whole so my CSS knowledge isn't too large, I've attempted to fill out the div for a custom sidebar but unless I add some kind of content in the div it doesn't actually fill out to the `min-height: 100%;` I started with `height: 100%,` and I've tried `height: auto;` as well as removing the padding and margin.

leads to my router-outlet which leads to my SideBar component

Styles.css

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url('assets/Images/HomeBack.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-size: 539px 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DadWebsite</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

SideBarTest.component.html

```
<div class="page-continer">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>HELLO</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

SideBarTest.component.css

```
.page-container
{
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar
{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
}
```

SideBarTest.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-SideBarTest',
  templateUrl: './SideBarTest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./SideBarTest.component.css']
})
export class SideBarTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Use `height: 100vh` to make its height equal to the height of viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `height: 100%` for sidebar, it will be 100% of its parent component. The parent of sidebar is **body** so it will take the **100% height** of **body**.

The parent of **body** is **html**, but you haven't added height for it.

#### First method

Add the height for **html** tag.

```
html {
height: 100%
}
```

#### Second method

Use `height: 100vh` for the **body** or **sidebar** to make the height of sidebar equal to the height of viewport i.e. full height of browser. In my opinion it will be better if you add it to body.

`100vh` means 100% of viewport height.

Comment: 1t method I tried, just see that the file name was cut on stackoverflow so you coulndt tell it was the html style css. The 2nd method did the trick tho. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `height: 100%` instead of `min-height: 100%`